# How to start Cmder minimized on Windows startup?

Tags: windows-10, cmder

I'd like to run Cmder minimized on Windows 10 startup? How can I do that (that may be AutoHotkey script).

I've tried the standard Windows-way of starting minimized application, i.e. Properties > Shortcut > Run=Minimized, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Create shortcut in windows startup folder and add /x /MIN to target field.

You can find your startup folder by running windows Run: shell:startup

/x is for running additional conemu arguments.

/MIN is for running conemu minimized on startup.

Example target field in your windows startup shortcut:

```
C:\apps\cmder\Cmder.exe /x /MIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to:

- Create a shortcut to the application
- Set the *Run* property to minimized
- Move the shortcut to the *Startup* Folder (%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup)

?

[image: Run an application minimized]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I've tried that and it doesn't work with Cmder.

Comment: @DariuszWoźniak Then maybe you should add that information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling this setting: `Main > Task bar > Taskbar status area > Auto minimize to TSA`.

Comment: Enabled, but it doesn't work either.